# not all Teams channels have sharepoint sites, is this normal

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am working on a new custom tenant, and for a Team it has 7 channels as follow:-

[image]

but for 6 channels there are not SharePoint sites, while only the above highlighted channel has a SharePoint site, so is this normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is normal. Standard channels have a folder in the Team's SharePoint site, while private channels have their own SharePoint site.

[Overview of Teams and SharePoint integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/teams-connected-sites)